# UITableview datasource and delegate

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, storyboard

For UITableView in storyboard have identity Inspector custom class as **ExamplesViewController** and then in the connection inspector have outlets for tableview dataSource and delegates as same **ExamplesViewController**.

Can i change somehow the outlets for tableview dataSource and delegates to some other class than ExamplesViewController and still keep the identity Inspector custom class as **ExamplesViewController**.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to change that?  If you are wanting something re-usable, why not consider subclassing instead of changing the delegate to something other than the ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Hover over the connections in Interface Builder. A small 'x' should appear, click it. This will break the current connections. Drag from the (now open) circle next to each property over to the new dataSource and delegate. This will set the new connections. None of this will change the class shown in Interface Builder.